# Google Distance Matrix API - Find distance between a given place and nearest bus stop, restaurant etc

Tags: google-maps

I need to use Google Distance API to find the distance between a given place and its nearest bus stop, ATM, Police station etc. But I am not being able to do so. Whenever I write ATM+CITYNAME, it gives some weird results. The destination it perceives is mostly thousands of kms away from the origin. I think I just need to know the format of the URL to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible in 1 step, the DistanceMatrix-API uses geocoding(which requires addresses or LatLng's), but what you are looking for are places.

First run a [places-nearbySearch](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) and then request the DistanceMatrix-Service based on the locations returned by the nearbySearch